# How would I make a bot that "host events" with Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js, pm2

I need a way to host "events" with Discord.js.

The closest I found was [this](https://devpost.com/software/discordbot).

This is exactly what I need it to do but this doesn't show any code to try and replicate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not see how this is a problem? What are you asking for? You want someone to write an entire bot for you? Please clarify your question. The general rule is to describe context, describe the problem, describe what you tried and not forget to include code snippets, logs, links to resources, etc... Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

```
  if(command === 'mnhost') {
var movie = args.join(" ");
let MNP = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Movie Night Pings");
if (!movie) return message.reply('Please specify the movie you are hosting! (Ex. `~mnhost <Movie Title>`)')


  message.channel.send(":partying_face: Are you ready for some movies?:partying_face:")
  message.channel.send(MNP + " :movie_camera: " + message.author + " is hosting __**" + movie + "**__!!! :movie_camera:")
}
```